# Deploying ARMv7 compiled code gets INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, java-native-interface, arm, native

My project includes native libraries compiled only for ARMv7. When I try to install it on Samsung Galaxy Y (which has ARMv6), I get `INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE` error.

However, I want to make my application deployable for every devices, no matter they have ARMv7 or not. If target device is an ARMv7, using native library will be a plus. That's it. For the rest of devices, application will do its job without calling native methods. (Because of libary has a large `.so` file, I don't want to include compilations for other architectures).

Any ideas to overcome this error ? How can I tell Android to ignore native libraries compiled for different architectures and make my APK deployable ?

PS. I'm seeking soultions rather than "creating mutiple APKs"

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, by looking trough the NDK documentation I found this interesting hint (look inside the NDK folder in docs/Programmers_Guide/html/md_3__key__topics__c_p_u__support__chapter_1-section_8__a_b_is.html):

1. put your library inside assets folder
2. at runtime detect the cpu architecture using this java call: String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
3. If the result is something like "armv71" copy the lib from your assets to your data directory in the lib subdir: /data/data/<package_name>/lib/
4. Now you can safely call System.loadLibrary(...)